# Getting random values between two column values in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has two columns:

```
structure(list(lowage = c(45, 15, 9, 51, 22, 45, 4, 4, 9, 25), 
    highage = c(50, 21, 14, 60, 24, 50, 8, 8, 14, 30)), .Names = c("lowage", 
"highage"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data frame looks like:

```
   lowage highage
1      45      50
2      15      21
3       9      14
4      51      60
5      22      24
6      45      50
7       4       8
8       4       8
9       9      14
10     25      30
```

I am trying to get a random number for each row between the two columns and save it as a third column.

I have tried the following:

```
df$age <- sample(df$lowage:df$highage,1)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, age, value = c(47L, 50L, 49L, 48L,  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 795
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In df$lowage:dfhighage :
  numerical expression has 795 elements: only the first used
2: In dflowage:df$highage :
  numerical expression has 795 elements: only the first used
```

I tried with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(df$lowage)) {
 df$age[i] <- round(sample(df$lowage[i]:df$highage[i]),1)
}
```

While this creates a column age with randomised age values, still it gives me the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In df$age[i] <- round(sample(df$lowage[i]:df$highage[i]),  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Though I could see values for each row in my df, I am not sure if this warning have an impact on the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` (row-wise) and generate a sequence of numbers between two columns and then select any 1 number from them using `sample`.

```
df$random_number <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(seq(x[1], x[2]), 1))

df

#   lowage highage random_number
#1      45      50            47
#2      15      21            21
#3       9      14             9
#4      51      60            55
#5      22      24            23
#6      45      50            47
#7       4       8             7
#8       4       8             8
#9       9      14            14
#10     25      30            27
```

---

Or similar concept with `mapply`

```
df$random_number <- mapply(function(x, y) sample(seq(x, y), 1), 
                    df$lowage, df$highage)
```